# How can I alternate an element’s background image on click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, background-image

I want to write a statement similar to this:

```
$("#something").click(function() {
    $('#something').css('background-image', 'url(image1.jpg)');
});
```

But what I want to do is say:

- if `#something`’s background is image1.jpg and it is clicked, then replace with image2.jpg
- if `#something`’s background is image2.jpg and it is clicked, then replace with image1.jpg

How can I do that?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee: what, aside from the code in the question?

Comment: @AtomicCockroach: what do you mean by “If #something *is* image1.jpg”? Do you mean if `#something`’s current `background-image` is `image1.jpg`?

Comment: @Arijit Mukherjee no code, just one div that's 200px x 200px with a bg image

Comment: @Paul, what i meant was, if the bg of the div is image1 then when clicked, i want it to change to image2, but then, i want the statement to check again once clicked, and if the div is image2 change to image1

Comment: So yes, you mean what I said. I’ve edited your question so that it says that too.

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#something").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', function(i, curimage) {
        if (curimage == 'url(image1.jpg)') {
            return 'url(image2.jpg)';
        } else {
            return 'url(image1.jpg)';
        }
    });
}
```

When the second argument to `.css()` is a function, it receives the current value and returns the new value.

Comment: The function you pass to `css()` takes two arguments: the index, first, and the current value, *second*. (Your six upvotes without anyone testing the answer make me cringe a little.)